# GDB on Solaris: /proc/168: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: c, gdb, solaris

I have a C application running on Solaris SPARC 8 that processes message off Websphere MQ and send them onto a target application.

The application runs unchanged on Solaris 10 and Linux 100%....no issues....

On this specific box it seems to run in say 4000 messages or more and on an AD HOC basis it just "hangs"...

So we installed GDB as I had the hope of attaching to the running process, so when I run something like:

gdb ./idoclink_inbound --pid=168 -tui I get the following output:

```
exec No process In:                                          Line: ??   PC: 0x0
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "sparc-sun-solaris2.8"...
Attaching to program `/opt/smq/idoclink/bin/idoclink_inbound', process 168
/proc/168: Value too large for defined data type.
do_attach: couldn't save traced faults.
(gdb) backtrace
No stack.
(gdb)
```

I really need to try find out what the process is doing, do you have any ideas what this issue could be?

It almost seems like a GDB bug?

Any advise or help would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Lynton

Comment: mmmm.....must be that GDB is possibly compiled in 32 bit mode, will need to recompile it in 64 bit mode...

Answer (score 1):

> GDB is possibly compiled in 32 bit mode

Your GDB is *definitely* built in 32-bit mode. If it was built in 64-bit mode, it would say `spacv9-sun-solaris...`.

Rebuilding in 64-bit mode is likely to solve the problem.